# using index after joined tables in oracle

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle19c

I would like to know what happens behind the scene  when a table has an index on a particular column but we want to use this column in a join with CTE table.

let say whe a CTE like this

with ds as (
select colx from table a
join table b on a.colx = b.coly
)
select * from ds
join table c on ds.colx = c.colz

so there is an index on colx in table a.
will oracle be able to use this index when joining table c to the new table ds?
Or this index gets lost and are used just when joining table a with table b.

thanks

Comment: Yes, no, maybe . . . Oracle both materializes CTEs and does in-place substitution of the logic.  So, it depends on which the optimizer decides to use.

Comment: Gordon is right, we cannot know what the optimizer decides to do. In this particular case the subquery is only used once in the query, though, so it is very likely Oracle just sees three tables joined and determines the best way to put this into action.